# CATProduct fail to convert

Tags: autodesk-forge

CATProduct format files with multiple CATPart format files are assembly relationships, and upload files in CATProduct format will fail to convert. Is there any way to solve this problem? Such as CATProduct format files and multiple CATPart format files or specify the relationship between the subordinate relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it usually works is that you either upload all the files in a zip and when translating you specify that it is a composite file and provide the rootFilename as well: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/translate-referenced-files-by-derivative-api.html, or if you are uploading to A360/Fusion Team/BIM 360 Docs, then you could also upload each file separately and then define the relationships between them: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/12/setting-up-references-between-files.html